# Assigning a function to a variable in Javascript & calling it with the declaration

Tags: javascript, function

I am coming from a Python background & have recently started learning Javascript. I am a bit hung up on how functions are assigned to variables & how they return data.

Please consider the following object:

```
const stats = {
    max: 53.8,
    min: 34.9,
    std: 6.5
};
```

When I just declare a plain function & log, I get the appropriate output:

```
function half(stats) {
    return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
};

console.log(half(stats));
```

However, the tutorial I am referring to uses a somewhat weird way to get the same thing done, like so:

```
const half = (function() {

    return function half(stats) {
        return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
    };
})();

console.log(half(stats));
```

What I do not understand here is:

1. The need for two nested returns (Seems fairly simple function, I don't see why we need 2 returns)
2. The parenthesis that starts before the `function` keyword & ends with the larger block
3. Most intriguingly, the `();` at the end of the entire block, implying the function is being called as soon as it is declared?

Also, when I try to rewrite the same thing in a simpler way using my experience in Python, that seems to do the trick as well. Like so:

```
const half = function(stats) {
    return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
};

console.log(half(stats));
```

Can anyone please explain to me what's happening in the code provided by the tutorial? Also, perhaps you can do so by answering the 3 questions I posed above. Thank you!

Comment: It's an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript). But I can't see any purpose for it in this case.

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial? Maybe there's some additional context that would explain why they did it this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @NineTails Which of the answers there explains why it's used in this case? There's no scoping in the IIFE that needs to be hidden.

Comment: @Barmar I can't tell without looking into the tutorial that OP mentions, hence I didn't mention a specific answer.

Comment: @NineTails My point is that I don't think there's any good reason why it's used in this case, so none of the answers would explain it.

Comment: Ok. I can now understand that it's an IIFE. So without the internal `half` function declaration, the external `half` variable will actually be assigned the returned value & not the function itself. But I do not understand how can it be immediately invoked without passing the required argument. For reference, the tutorial comes from the following YT video from freeCodeCamp.org : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg&t=11105s

Answer (score 0):

Refer this.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp ( towards the end )

Comment: Except it's not closing over any variables. This is just an IIFE.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I will take  care of that. Thanks for the suggestion. @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of concepts you have to know here,

**Function declaration**

```
 function half(stats) {
        return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
    };
    
    console.log(half(stats));
```

**Function expression**

```
 const half = function(stats) {
        return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
    };
    
    console.log(half(stats));
```

Read more - https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

**Immediately invoked function expression**

```
const half = (function() {

    return function half(stats) {
        return (stats.min + stats.max) / 2.0;
    };
})(); // this will immediately execute without any invocation

console.log(half(stats));
```

Read more here - http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html

closure - https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/closure-in-javascript

Comment: So, for the IIFE, is it able to immediately execute without any arguments because it only returns the uninvoked internal function? If so, what's the purpose of the internal function & immediate execution? Wouldn't it be simpler to just use a function expression like in your example?

Comment: your use case IIFE is not needed.